# Access Windows Authentication information from within web part

Tags: 2007, windows-authentication

We have a company intranet where users are automatically logged in using integrated windows authentication.

Is there any way for a web part to grab some of their account information such as full name, email and dept?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on you having a correct synchronization between AD and SharePoint User Profile Service, you can use the UserProfileManager from the webpart's code behind to grab the users profile and retrieve data: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.server.userprofiles.userprofilemanager.aspx

There is a basic example at the link of how to work it, and you can find more on the web.